# Cakephp: Populate form options

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to populate a dropdown field inputbox with custom values:

```
echo $form->input('cities', array('div' => false, 'options' => $customCities));
```

in my controller:

```
public function find() {
  $this->Journey->recursive = 2;
  $ticities = $this->Journey->toACity->find('all');
  $customCities = array();
  foreach ($ticities as $tCities):
  foreach ($tCities as $ap):
   if(array_key_exists('id',$ap)){$customCities[]=$ap['name']);}
  endforeach;
  endforeach;
  $this->set('customCities', $customCities);
 ....
```

This allows me to set values for the dropdown box. But the dropdown box' entries' ids do not correspond to the Cities' real ids. -> All entries in the dropdown box have the default id (0,1,2,3...).

How can i set a custom value for each drop down entry. I tried:

$customCities[]=array($ap['id'],$ap['name']));

But this doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this part

```
$customCities[]=$ap['name'];
```

to

```
$customCities[$ap['id']]=$ap['name'];
```

finally looks like

```
if(array_key_exists('id',$ap)){$customCities[$ap['id']]=$ap['name'];}
```

Comment: thanks! that does the trick! i will accept it as soon as I am allowed to.

Comment: BTW: If anyone else needs further information on how this works: http://book.cakephp.org/view/192/options-options

Comment: why not just using find('list') ?